# Attaching events to images inside iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have an iframe (with id=iframe) and I am trying to attach onClick event to each one. The iframe is within the domain.

```
$("#iframe").contents().find('img').each(function () {
    $(this).on('click', function (event) {
        $('#image-box', window.parent.document).show(300);
        window.parent.document.getImage(this);
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need to specify ".document" when calling a function in the parent because JS is not in the document itself.

Comment: Thanks, still no joy, but will avoid frustration later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to load the iframe first otherwise it wouldn't work. The solution, therefore, looks like this:

```
var iframe = $("#iframe");
iframe.load(function () {
    iframe.contents().find('img').each(function () {
        $(this).on('click', function (event) {
            $('#image-box', window.parent.show(300));
            window.parent.getImage(this);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your iframe there is no jquery, you should use Jquery functions from your parent window instead. I dont remember now if jQuery function in on the document or in the window browser object.

```
$("#iframe").contents().find('img').each(function () {
    $(this).on('click', function (event) {
        window.parent.document.$('#image-box', window.parent.document).show(300);
        window.parent.document.getImage(this);
    });
});
```

Hope it helps...